# UNKNOWN_ERROR occurred on UPDATE of LWC Component VSCode

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, vs-code

I am attempting to update an LWC component using VSCode. I am able to successfully create the LWC if it currently does not exist in the sandbox - but any effort to update it fails with the following errors

What is interesting about this is if I manually delete the component, it will allow me to create a new one - but there is no discernible error associated with the deployment which is making troubleshooting difficult.

**EDIT: Can successfully edit all other files in the directory. In particular there is a controller going over with this LWC and it works fine - just not the LWC component**

Have tried:

- Updating SFDX
- Refreshing Sandbox
- Changing API version

Any help would be appreciated

VSCode

[image]

Deployment Settings:

[image]

Comment: Does `tail ~/.sfdx/sfdx.log` show anything more?

Comment: I've got two error codes: ENOENT and "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE". Invalid argument doesn't make sense as it deploys on create, but not on edit

Comment: Should mention there are no 'Problems' under the Problems tab

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Meta file contained <analytics_Dashboard> - once removed, the updates deploy successfully.